# Will race condition occur when I multithreading a script that get source code from a website? [PYTHON]

Tags: python, multithreading, locking, urllib, race-condition

Let say I would like to scrape data from a website for this stock code using urllib:

```
> sourceURL =
> urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.aastocks.com/tc/stocks/quote/quick-quote.aspx?symbol=00001")
```

And I would use beautifulsoup to get the data from the sourceURL, however, as I have a list of stocks would do the same job, so I intend to use multithread to speed up the process.

However, I heard that multithread might cause race condition, so in this case, do I need to apply a lock as follow:

```
lock.acquire()
sourceURL = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.aastocks.com/en/stocks/analysis/company-fundamental/basic-information?symbol=00001").read()
lock.release()
```

As far as I know, this process urlopen method take the most time in my script, would that be pointless to apply thread if lock is really necessary to avoid data corruption in the sourceURL or it does not really need one as the function of urlopen itself does not have any variables but just get all the source code to the sourceURL?

Besides, as some part of the website I used selenium chromedriver to browse it which takes even more time, is lock necessary too?

```
    url = 'http://www.aastocks.com/en/stocks/quote/detail-quote.aspx?symbol=00001'
    browser.get(url) 
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="sb2-btnSubmit"]').click()
    source = browser.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML")
```

Is urllib or urllib3, selenium webdriver thread-safe?

Comment: you might want to understand what exactly happens to be the issues with race conditions. if you're reading different or even the same resource and not actually modifying it, it doesn't matter if there's a race condition, if youre not sharing the data between the processes or something.

Comment: As I wouldnt want to dive into the source code of urllib, urllib3 or selenium webdriver methods to check if there is any global variables or sharing variables amongs the threads etc

Comment: you should be good to go.

Comment: so do I need to use any lock?

Comment: I again encourage you, read up on race conditions, and then just ask yourself logical questions about why and when they are a problem, and when they are not. i can give you the answer (no, you do not need a lock) but you're really not doing yourself a favour if you do not take away anything from this conversation.